# Error while adding "moderation" in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to use django-moderation in my Django project. I have downloaded the app with pip3, the issue is when I added the app to `INSTALLED_APPS`, I have the following exception. Can you please advise how to get rid of this?

```
python3 manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x1024977b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moderation/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class ModeratedObject(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moderation/models.py", line 43, in ModeratedObject
    editable=False)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete
```

Comment: check you Django version, on_delete in required after 2.0 but it seems moderation is not up to date with it

Comment: thanks ,latest commit on the master branch helped fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest release of [Django-moderation](https://pypi.org/project/django-moderation/) was in 2017, so it doesn't support Django 2.

Pull request [#169](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation/commit/565481f1832114da2d0c48b0c23977d4d3a9b914) for Django 2 has been merged, but there hasn't been a release since then. You could try installing the latest commit on the master branch, for example:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/dominno/django-moderation.git@565481f1832114da2d0c48b0c23977d4d3a9b914
```

(in your case, you would use `pip3` instead of `pip`, but it would be a good idea to start using virtual environments instead of the system Python. Once you have activated a Python 3 virtual environment, you use `python` and `pip` instead of `python3` and `pip3`.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair for the help,your input help me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your `ModeratedObject` model in `moderation/models.py` you have a model field ForeignKey with missing on_delete argument.

See example from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Additional documentation on on_delete argument is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#arguments).

Comment: thanks Borut,it's a package I have installed ,I didn't create any related model file yet afterwards.